# What did Robespierre think of Huguenots?

Tags: france, french-revolution, religious-history, protestant-church

I've been reading up recently about the Huguenots ("French Protestants" could be synonym) and how they lived, and this question intrigues me- *Did Maximilien Robespierre have anything to say about the Huguenots and Protestantism in general?*

I already understand that under his rule, he [declared atheism to be the official religion of the French State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dechristianization_of_France_during_the_French_Revolution), and that he was a fierce anti-Catholic, but I can't find anything about what he said about Huguenots. Could you help me?

Comment: What results have you found in your previous research as to the percentage of protestants in France after the persecution of protestants officially ended with the Edict of Versailles in 1787? Todays estimate is around 2% of the population. Do you think that 2% would be matter of great concern to Robespierre?

Comment: He was concerned about aristocrats, what % were they?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I can't find any numbers about the percentage of Huguenots back then, but Robespierre did have opinions on other minorities, like Jews (https://revolution.chnm.org/d/283), and he did also have some about slaves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_4_February_1794)

Comment: If you have information about other minorities (jews, slaves ; percentage of population and measures made against them by Robespierre) and add this information (with source) to your question showing previous research. What was the reason for Robespierre's fierce anti-Catholic/aristocrats attitude (because of the willingness of neighbouring countries to support these groups by invading France and destroying the republic/revolution?). All of this background information is lacking in your question.

Comment: You will more likely get a reasonable answer to your core question (was this also true towards protestants/huguenots?) when your question shows Robespierre's attitude/motives towards other minorities.

Comment: My guess is that by that time there were insufficient of them left in France to have been of a distinct interest to revolutionaries. And I believe they had historically been heavily concentrated in one or two regions - one was the Cevennes. Hordes of them left in the 17th century for protestant countries like Britain, and - especially into Geneva and the French-speaking parts of Switzerland, where Calvinism held out.